# Exception not showing Source Lines in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Recently my Visual Studio 2012 has stopped opening the source line when an exception is thrown and double clicking the line in the callstack doesn't go to the source line either.

I'm using visual studio 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL and have .NET 4.5.51209 installed.
This is occurring in a .net 3.5 asp.net web application.

I have resharper 7.1.3 installed as well, though that has never caused this issue before.

How do I fix it?

Update:
I created a new vb.net Empty Web application, added a Default.aspx that throws an exception, and have the same problems. (Being that it doesn't automatically navigate to the line of code with the exception, and also doesn't navigate when double clicking on the top of the call stack)
I used the following test line:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim x As String
    x = "hello world"
    Throw New Exception("oh no")
End Sub
```

here's my visual studio Info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51209

Installed Version: Ultimate

Architecture and Modeling Tools   04940-004-0038003-02335
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012   04940-004-0038003-02335
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012

Visual Basic 2012   04940-004-0038003-02335
Microsoft Visual Basic 2012

Visual C# 2012   04940-004-0038003-02335
Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Visual C++ 2012   04940-004-0038003-02335
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012

Visual F# 2012   04940-004-0038003-02335
Microsoft Visual F# 2012

Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker   04940-004-0038003-02335
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

JetBrains ReSharper 7.1.3   Full Edition build 7.1.3000.2254 on 2013-04-10T22:48:18
JetBrains ReSharper 7.1.3 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2014 JetBrains, Inc.

NuGet Package Manager   2.0.30625.9003
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.40706.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

StyleCop   4.7.49.0
Provides source code style and consistency tools. See http://www.stylecop.codeplex.com/ for more details.

Web Developer Tools   1.0.30710.0
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Page Inspector: Tool that offers an efficient way to decompose Web Applications and diagnose front-end issues.
Web Publishing: Extensions required for Web Publishing for both hosted servers as well as on premises.
Web Form Templates: Includes the default templates for Web Form Applications.
Editor Extensions: Includes HTML, CSS, and JS editor extensions that greatly enhance the development experience.
```

Comment: Is this for all projects or just one? Have you tried completely cleaning and rebuilding the project?  From VS, choose Clean Solution, then close VS, manually delete the \bin and \obj folders for the project(s), then re-open, build, and debug in VS.

Comment: Also, perhaps the exception is thrown by a background or external process? Try putting a `throw new InvalidOperationException("MyTest");` line somewhere in your normal app flow to see if it correctly stops on that point.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie I tried creating a new vb project and doing the throw new exception and had the same problem

Comment: Press CTRL D+E or go to the debug menu and then exceptions and see what you have set there.  have you tried it in a non web project? if web only is it cassini, iis express or iis?

Comment: reset vs settings from tools->import export settings, it looks like a configuration issue

Comment: @MikeMiller I have it showing all exceptions when thrown, and the new project uses iis express, and the old project uses iis

Comment: @sarepta I'll keep that in mind if it comes up again, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a fix.

1. Rebuild Solution
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Open IIS and stop the web server
4. recycle all application pools
5. Clean out the Temporary Internet Files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework#version#\Temporary ASP.NET Files

After that the test project, and the original project worked as expected.